# Doxygen filter script breaks auto-link generation

Tags: c, documentation, doxygen

I’m trying to fix some proprietary compiler directives by using a filter. I discovered that if I pass a file through a filter, the file documentation is generated correctly, but auto-linking seems broken!

I came up with a very simple example. My filter is implemented in Python and it just opens the file and prints every single line, it doesn’t change anything. I confirmed this by comparing the filter’s input and output (by redirection) with a diff and there are no differences at all.

I redirected the filter’s output to a file called filtered_c.h. If I include this file as a source file, I get auto-link to work. If I pass the original header file through the filter, auto-linking is broken and I get a warning

```
latex_double.md:7: warning: unable to resolve reference to `some_c_function' for \ref command
```

If I comment out the `FILTER_PATTERNS` line in the Doxyfile, auto-linking works.

This is really an issue for me, as I’m also supporting parsing assembly files through a filter script and I see the same behavior there: the file documentation is perfect, but no auto-linking.

I'm using Doxygen 1.8.15 in windows 10.

Any thoughts are very welcome! Thanks!

Doxyfile:

```
# General options
PROJECT_NAME          = "Double table headers in LaTeX"

INPUT                 = doc/latex_double.md
INPUT                 += include/regular_c.h
#INPUT                 += filtered_c.h

#You should not need to change the rest of the file
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = output_doc
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES

FILTER_PATTERNS       += *.h="c:\Python27\python filter\dummy_filter.py"
```

Filter Script:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.exit(1)

def extract_globals(filename):

    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                print(line, end='')

extract_globals(sys.argv[1])
```

Markdown source:

```
# Chapter Title {#chapter_title}

Some text here

# Introduction {#chapter_intro}

Loren Ipsum @ref some_c_function
```

regular_c.h

```
/**
 * @file regular_c.h
 * @brief This is a simple C header file with some examples.
 */

#ifndef REGULAR_C_H_
#define REGULAR_C_H_

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * If building with a C++ compiler, make all of the definitions in this header
 * have a C binding.
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif    /* ifdef __cplusplus */

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Include files
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Defines
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Global variables and types
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
 * This enumeration has the return codes for the @ref some_c_function function.
 */
typedef enum __SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN {
    SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_everthing_ok        = 0,    ///< Nothing to see here
    SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_some_weird_error,           ///< This is not the error you're looking for
    SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_some_very_bad_error,        ///< This is not the error we are looking for
    SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_life_is_sad_just_cope       ///< Move along
} SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN;

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function prototype definitions
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * @brief Some C function that is here just as an example.
 *
 * This function doesn't actually do anything useful.
 *
 * @param[in]   v   We do something with this value.
 * @param[out]  ptr Some value will be written here.
 *
 * @return Returns a value that depends on what happened:
 * - @ref SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_everthing_ok
 *        Uh, everything is under control. Situation normal.
 * - @ref SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_some_weird_error
 *        Uh, had a slight weapons malfunction.
 * - @ref SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_some_very_bad_error
 *        We had a reactor leak here now. Give us a few minutes to lock it down.
 *        Large leak... very dangerous.
 * - @ref SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_life_is_sad_just_cope
 *        Who is this?? What's your operating number?
 *
 */
int some_c_function(uint32_t v, void* ptr);

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Close the 'extern "C"' block
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif    /* ifdef __cplusplus */

#endif /* REGULAR_C_H_ */
```

filtered_c.h

```
/**
 * @file filtered_c.h
 * @brief This is a simple C header file with some examples.
 */

#ifndef REGULAR_C_H_
#define REGULAR_C_H_

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * If building with a C++ compiler, make all of the definitions in this header
 * have a C binding.
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif    /* ifdef __cplusplus */

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Include files
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Defines
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Global variables and types
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/**
 * This enumeration has the return codes for the @ref some_c_function function.
 */
typedef enum __SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN {
    SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_everthing_ok        = 0,    ///< Nothing to see here
    SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_some_weird_error,           ///< This is not the error you're looking for
    SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_some_very_bad_error,        ///< This is not the error we are looking for
    SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_life_is_sad_just_cope       ///< Move along
} SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN;

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Function prototype definitions
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * @brief Some C function that is here just as an example.
 *
 * This function doesn't actually do anything useful.
 *
 * @param[in]   v   We do something with this value.
 * @param[out]  ptr Some value will be written here.
 *
 * @return Returns a value that depends on what happened:
 * - @ref SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_everthing_ok
 *        Uh, everything is under control. Situation normal.
 * - @ref SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_some_weird_error
 *        Uh, had a slight weapons malfunction.
 * - @ref SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_some_very_bad_error
 *        We had a reactor leak here now. Give us a few minutes to lock it down.
 *        Large leak... very dangerous.
 * - @ref SOME_C_FUNCTION_RETURN_life_is_sad_just_cope
 *        Who is this?? What's your operating number?
 *
 */
int some_c_function(uint32_t v, void* ptr);

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Close the 'extern "C"' block
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif    /* ifdef __cplusplus */

#endif /* REGULAR_C_H_ */
```

Comment: Strange problem, linking should still work. I tried with doxygen version 1.8.15 on Windows 7 (but the later should not give a problem) and was not able to reproduce the problem. Please retest and when persistent create an issue at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new with attached attach a, small, self contained example (source+configuration file in a tar or zip) that allows us to reproduce the problem?  Please don't add external links as they might not be persistent.

Comment: @albert, thanks for your reply. I have tested this on a Linux VM (Ubuntu 18.04,Doxygen Linux binary 1.8.16,  Python 3.6.8) I get the expected behaviour.

I'll fill a bug.

Thanks!

Comment: With expected behavior do  you mean an error  / wrong results or the normal result with the link?

Comment: @albert I mean Doxygen in Linux generates the correct documentation.

I've created a bug report:

https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7222.

Cheers!